# Converting set of string values to numeric values

Tags: python, set, converters

I have 2 sets: one with string values and the other with numeric values.

How can I convert a set of string values into a set of numeric values so that it can can be used with:

`set.difference(csv1,csv2)`

```
csv1 = ({92599, 95571, 95382, 95383})

csv2 = ({'92599', '95571', '95382', '95383'})
```

in to this

```
csv2 = ({92599, 95571, 95382, 95383})
```

Comment: Note that the parenthesis are not needed to create a set literal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [set comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-sets-and-dictionaries):

```
csv2 = {int(n) for n in csv2}
```

or, for Python versions prior to Python 2.7, use a generator expression:

```
csv2 = set(int(n) for n in csv2)
```

Demo:

```
>>> csv2 = {'92599', '95571', '95382', '95383'}
>>> {int(n) for n in csv2}
set([95571, 95383, 95382, 92599])
>>> set(int(n) for n in csv2)
set([95571, 92599, 95382, 95383])
```

To create the difference, just call the `set.difference()` method on `csv1` *directly*:

```
>>> csv1 = {92599, 95571, 95382, 95383}
>>> csv2 = {int(n) for n in csv2}
>>> csv1.difference(csv2)
set([])
```

or use the `-` subtraction operator for the same operation:

```
>>> csv1 - csv2
set([])
```

Comment: Are there any advantages of a comprehension over ```map(int, csv2)```?

Comment: @wnnmaw The advantage of this is that it actually returns a set.

Comment: @wnnmaw: In Python 2 `map()` creates a list object. In Python 3 you get a generator object. In both cases you'd still have to call `set()` on that first, making it two function calls (with associated stack pushes) instead of a pure-syntax solution.

Comment: @Martin Pieters Any other solution since i'm stuck in python 2.6 and it seems set comprehensions is not supported there ?

Comment: @JorgeVidinha: I added an alternative for Python 2.6 and older.

Comment: @JorgeVidinha: However, the set literal syntax you used in your post is not available before 2.7 either.

Comment: @Martin Pieters Yes the post is on an env test using 2.7 Thank you the set(int(n) for n in csv2) seems to work at this stage.

Answer (score 1):

```
csv2 = set(int(n) for n in csv2)
```

is what you want.

Output:

```
set([92599, 95571, 95382, 95383])
```